# Setting up VPN on windows rather than router

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have the Netgear router which has build in VPN capability.
They have their own VPN client software to make VPN connection but i am not able to connect using that.

Is there any way from where i can make VPN directly to my server without coming through the router and installing third party software

I have windows 2008 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Would Windows 2008 NPS (RADIUS Service) work for you? I have used Radius on win 2003 to simulate a VPN like feature in the past.

[here's something for better understanding.](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Understanding-new-Windows-Server-2008-Network-Policy-Server.html)